# How to plot a line between two previous values in pine script for trading view

Tags: pine-script

I would like to plot a line from ohlc4 (1) (one candle back from current) and ohlc4 for 10 candles back. I would like the line to just be from point to point not extending for ever in either direction.

Any coding masters out there that could enlighten me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will plot the requested line.

```
//@version=4
study("OHLC line", "OHLC", overlay=true)

var line    myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index[1],  ohlc4[1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index[10], ohlc4[10])
```